# error "data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible" on SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have recently started getting this error when trying to update a pre-existing record:

> The data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 108:                    streamEntryTable.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, entry);
>
> Line 109:                }
>
> Line 110:                streamEntryTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
>
> Source File: C:\Path\Genesis.Domain\Concrete\SqlGenesisRepositoryEntryPartial.cs    Line: 110
>
> Stack Trace: 
>       [SqlException (0x80131904): The data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.]

What would trigger a comparison like that? I have been able to perfom CRUD functions on this table previously.

What could trigger that comparison?

### Edit

C# POCO for the linqTOsql:

```
[Table]
public class StreamEntry
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public long seID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an entry URL.")]
    [Column]
    public string seUrl { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an entry headline.")]
    [Column]
    public string seHeadline { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string seBody { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string seDescription { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string seKeywords { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string seTitle { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public long seOrder { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public DateTime seDateCreated { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public DateTime seDateModified { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public long StreamID { get; set; } // FK
    [Column]
    public bool AllowComments { get; set; }

    // Relationship (many entries to one stream)
    // using EntityRef<Stream> and ThisKey
    // which is "This" table FK
    private EntityRef<Stream> _Stream;
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_Stream", ThisKey = "StreamID")]
    public Stream Stream
    {
        get { return this._Stream.Entity; }
        set { this._Stream.Entity = value; }
    }

    // relationship (one entry to many FieldInstances) 
    // uses EntitySet<FieldInstance> and OtherKey for the FK in FieldInstance 
    // which is the "Other" table.
    private EntitySet<FieldInstance> _FieldInstance = new EntitySet<FieldInstance>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_FieldInstance", OtherKey = "fiStreamEntryID")]
    public EntitySet<FieldInstance> FieldInstance
    {
        get { return this._FieldInstance; }
        set { this._FieldInstance.Assign(value); }
    }

}
```

StreamEntry table definition

> seID bigint notnull
>
> seUrl nvarchar(255) notnull
>
> seHeadline nvarchar(255) notnull
>
> seBody ntext nullable
>
> seDescription  nvarchar(255) nullable
>
> seKeywords nvarchar(255) nullable
>
> seTitle nvarchar(255) nullable
>
> seOrder bigint notnull
>
> seDateCreated datetime notnull
>
> seDateModified datetime notnull
>
> StreamID bigint notnull
>
> AllowComments bit notnull

### Edit2 - more details about error

I can successfully `SubmitChanges()` if the `seBody` form field is empty. If I add text to `seBody` it will update correctly. But, from that point, any attempts to `SubmitChanges()` return the error above.

Comment: Did the table schema change? Sounds like one of your field types changed.

Comment: What is your query and your table structure?

Comment: @leppie: explain further please...

Comment: @Coding Gorilla - Yes... the table changed in the db and the POCO table object that linq is using also changed... but the changes are reflected in the db and the C# code.

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL (AFAIK) doesn't support "POCO", so I'm not sure if you're just mixing your terminology or not.  But it certainly sounds like something is out of sync here.  Without seeing some of the code and models though, its hard to tell.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla - I'll edit my question with more code in just a moment. Also, one of linq-to-sql's strengths (IMHO) is it's POCO support. If you can, refer to page 55 of Steven Sanderson's book Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework, he talks about his decision to have his examples in linqtosql is because of it's early POCO support. That is, earlier support than Entitie Framework. With .NET 4 Entity Framework supports POCO.

Comment: So what SQL does it create?  And BTW ntext is deprecated, you might want to change that to nvarchar(max).

Comment: @HLGEM - ntext is depricated??? should I use nvarchar(MAX) instead? I bet that's my issue. I'm using sql server 2008.

As far as SQL... the SQL is coming from linq-to-sql. I don't know what it is.

Comment: @quakkels I stand corrected about the POCO stuff, I'd not seen that in relation to LINQ-to-SQL before.  But it still seems something is out of sync, I'd be curious as was HLGEM as to what the SQL statement it's generating.  It's clearly trying to do a comparison of some sort, which doesn't make sense if you're just doing an update.  Maybe there's a trigger or someting that wasn't updated when the schema changed?

Comment: ntext is deprecaed, but it's still available in SQL Server 2008.  While making that change back to nvarchar(max) probably will solve your problem, I don't think that's the underlying problem here.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla / @HLGEM - Is there a way I can see the sql that gets generated by l2s?

Also, could it be that linq-to-sql simply doesn't handle ntext well?

Comment: You can get a demo copy of L2S Profiler at: http://l2sprof.com/  I've never had a problems with ntext, but to be honest I don't use L2S very much.  Did you check on triggers?

Comment: @quakkels, yes there is a way, but I don't use it so, I can't help you there, someone here should be able to tell you.  And I'm not sure that chanign it willsolve your problem becasue it was complaining about nvarchar as well. That's why I want to see the SQL it generated.

Comment: @gbn: What's to explain? You cannot do it in SQL. At least not in any MS SQL product. The same reason why you cant join on ntext columns and not use LIKE on ntext columns, etc.

Comment: @quakkels: You may want to decorate you Column attributes with native SQL type info to prevent the error before hitting SQL. It still does not solve the problem. You only get the error earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the discussion and information in the comments of my question. Preliminary solution was to change the `ntext` field to an `nvarchar(MAX)` field. That took care of all the errors. This doesn't mean that I'm not going to revisit this issue once I've figured out how to use tools like l2sprof.com to view the generated SQL.

But, for the time being, the issue is solved by using `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: That is the proper way to do it, if you really need to use the textual data for lookups/searching/etc.